# Custom Build Action for sqlproj

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I came across [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/10/06/477064.aspx) which will add a custom "Build Action" option to the properties window for csproj. However, I would like to have a custom Build Action for the objects in a database project. Is there something I can add to the .sqlproj file that can do something similar? Can I add a custom Build Action at all for SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit sqlproj file and add your own msbuild target to it. It'll be equal to post\pre-build action.

**Edited**:
.SQLProj file is actually MSBuild script file (if we are both talking about SSDT SQL Database project one :)). So you can open it in any text editor and add something like this:

```
<Target Name="PreBuildEvent" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="calc.exe" />
</Target>
```

It'll be very close to the way how PreBuild command being executed to build process.
Check that PrepareForBuild target is being called during your build process or change it to any other you want. You can go further and extend your build process with any msbuild tasks you want.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you have an example of what to add to the .sqlproj file to add a custom "Build Action" for a SQL Proj?

Comment: added it to my answer.