# Publish data with SSDT with new feature Build Contributors and Deployment Plan

Tags: sql, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSDT-project. When publishing a new version I want to publish/initialize some data motion in the database as well. This can be done with new feature, but how ? [Announcing SQL Server Data Tools - June 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/24/announcing-sql-server-data-tools-june-2013.aspx)

Comment: Where is the logic that moves the data - in an SP or in SSIS?

Comment: @SAS SP SSIS I don't know what is it ? The logic is for example create empty row in a new table, to add the id in a foreign key in existing table who now requiering foreign key

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probaly using a Post Deployment Script.

You create the script to modify the data and include it in your post deployment script file.

I am assuming you have the script itself already, otherwise that is propably a separate question. For static data, Merge-statements are my recommendation.

Comment: I want to attach a different script for each publish.

Comment: OK, can you test inside the script if it should be executed or not? For example if there is a log table that tells if it was already executed, of a test against @@SERVERNAME if it is dependent on the target server?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. What I know to do It's write a post script always executed when I publish(always the same). What I want is create One script for each publish and keep all version to be able to apply all versionning to a new data base. hope it's clearer ;)

Comment: Well you need some logic to determine what script is to be executed, I guess(?)

Comment: The logic to determine what script is needed to be executed will be the version number.

Comment: You are maintaining several live versions of your Project in TFS? How are you separating the versions - different branches or just changesets?

Comment: I don't use TFS (Maybe I should ?) I use just git. I have 3 environments, Production, Quality and Dev. In my Git, I have just one branche, and I override everything In each commit. It's pretty simple and efficient. BUT can't manage my data motion problem.

Comment: No problem, but you need some way to determine what Environment you are publishing to. We do it with SQL in the scripts: IF @@SERVERNAME='PROD' ... and then put the logic for that target inside the IF.

Comment: I think that I find a simple way to do it. I should use snapshot. And when I need datamotion, generate one snapshot, then the script and optionnaly a second snapshot If I need recover some contrains. Can't find an easy way on vs2013 to pusblish a snapshot (dacpac) easily. I found juste sqlpackage.exe, but in command line. Is there a way to publish a dacpac easily directy in vs ?

Comment: sqlpackage can be used to publish usinga dacpac as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: You can test a variable and set that in your Publish Profile. We've done that to handle permissions and some environment-specific scripting. Something like this may help: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/trick-to-not-run-prepost-sql-on-publish.html

Comment: To make extensive use of variables when publishing, an controlling what gets executed where, and keep track of what's deployed where, we use this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923573/how-to-apply-transforms-to-ssdt-publish-profiles/27924631#27924631

Answer (score 0):

You can create a post-deployment script and put there MERGE statements which will populate your tables.
A MERGE command will generate relevant INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements to meet your desired data. The general idea is to write such command that will work for all publishes (only one script for all publishes). You can also embed such statements into IF EXISTS check, for example to check if a table/column exists.

More info you can read here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/02/02/including-data-in-an-sql-server-database-project.aspx