# Combine SQL files with command `copy` in a batch file introduce an incorrect syntaxe because it does add an invisible character `U+FEFF`

Tags: sql, batch-file, copy, pre-build-event

In a pre-build event, a batch file is executed  to combine multiple SQL files into a single one.
It is done using this command :

```
COPY %@ProjectDir%\Migrations\*.sql %@ProjectDir%ContinuousDeployment\AllFilesMergedTogether.sql
```

Everything appear to work fine but somehow the result give an incorrect syntaxe error.
After two hours of investigation, it turn out the issue is caused by an invisible character that remain invisible even with notepad++.
Using an online website, the character has been spotted and is `U+FEFF` has shown in following image.
[image]

Here are the two input scripts.
`PRINT 'Script1'`

`PRINT 'Script2'`

Here is the output given by the copy command.
`PRINT 'Script1'
PRINT 'Script2'`

Additional info :

- Batch file is encoded with UTF-8
- Input files are encoded with UTF-8-BOM
- Output file is encoded with UTF-8-BOM.
  I'm not sure it is possible to change the encoding output of command `copy`.
  I've tried and failed.

**What should be done to eradicate this extremely frustrating parasitic character?**

Comment: Batch files use OEM not UTF 8. Don't use batch file to do this. It is the byte order mark you are complaining about. It is also wrong for Windows as your BOM says it a big endian number `UTF-16 (BE) FE FF 254 255 þÿ` or `UTF-32 (BE) 00 00 FE FF 0 0 254 255 ␀␀þÿ`.

Answer (score 0):

It has turned out that changing encoding of input files to `ANSI` does fix the issue.
No more pesky character(s).
Also, doing so does change the encoding of the result file to `UTF-8` instead of `UTF-8-BOM` which is great I believe.

Encoding can be changed using Notepad++ as show in following picture.
[image]